# Differences between Jbutton and Jpanel and JFrame ?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jframe, jpanel

i make simple game , and it consist of 2 files , first file is "Alibaba.java" which is extended from JFrame , i used it to display general contents of the game !,

and the second file is "intro.java" which is extended from JPanel , i used it to show intro of the game which include (title & background & person) ,

my problem occured when i tried to add a simple button in the intro ! , i did a function to create the button , but the problem is when i run the game , the button which i added it don't appear !! , but when i tried add it from the first file which extended from JFrame , its appeared ! , 
so what is the problem in my code ? is JPanel don't accept JButtons ! or i must create the buttons from the JFrame file ?!

so i need to know how to add Jbutton inside Jpanel instead of add Jbutton in JFrame Direct !!,

this is my samples of my codes which contain the problem :

1st file (Alibaba.java)

```
package alibaba;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Alibaba extends JFrame {

    public Alibaba(){
        super("Alibaba");    


        Intro intro =   new Intro();
        this.add(intro);


        GraphicsEnvironment environment =   GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice  device  =   environment.getDefaultScreenDevice();

        device.setFullScreenWindow(this);    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        Alibaba alibaba =   new Alibaba();
    }
}
```

2nd file(Intro.java) :

```
package alibaba;


import javax.swing.JButton;




public class Intro extends javax.swing.JPanel implements Runnable{

    Thread _intro_run;

    public Intro() {
        _intro_run  =   new Thread(this);
        _intro_run.start();
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

    // Here i tried to add a button to the Intro !!! 

        this.add(this.createbutton("Exit"));
    }


    public JButton createbutton(String text){

        JButton _button  = new JButton(text);

        return _button;
    }

}
```

So please tell me what is the problem and how to solve it , sorry but iam new to java , new to programming games world ! ,, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the `JButton` inside the main thread, cross thread `Component` manipulation is bad.

For example:

```
public Intro() {
    JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
    this.add(exitButton);
}
```

Alternatively, use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)`. For example, in your run method:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            add(createbutton("Exit"));
        }
    }
}
```

Based on discussion it seems that you are overriding the `paint` or `paintComponent` methods. You need to call `super` in them, like:

```
void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    // do other stuff to g
}
```

Comment: i add this but th same problem !! , no buttons appears !!

Comment: @Jason4Ever Are you sure this is the code you run? I copied it on my machine and it shows a button.

Comment: hello , it's samples of my original code , my original code have additional lines to draw a background image& text image and code to set color of background

Comment: Oh if you are overriding the paint method, you NEED to call super first. Thats probably the issue. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Jason4Ever Then I suppose the error is somewhere else in your code. Did you maybe override the paint method?

Comment: hello, i Overrriding the paint method , but i don't think that the problem is from it ! , any way i called super.paint(g) in the first , but the problem still occure !

Comment: @Jason4Ever you're probably drawing over the button then.

Comment: thanks all for your help :)
@jli i solved the prboelm by set  a layout for jpanel , and i put super.paint(g) at the first line inside paint() method , and it's work but the problem now really is the big image which i draw it by paint() is drawing over the button , so the button dont appear , so please tell me how to make the button above the painted image ? and prevent this image from hdding it ?

Comment: @Jason4Ever You can call super after you draw your large image.

Comment: Also as kleopatra mentioned, it's preferred to override `paintComponent` rather than `paint`.

Comment: @jli really thank you very very much !! , i used paintComponent instead of paint !! , and it's solved all problems !! , as i readed that paintComponent is prefered because it recall paint again after doing some processes , please additional question , why i must call super() inside paint method ? what it will do ?? sorry for this additional question :$ , and thanks for all again , and thank you :)

Comment: @Jason4Ever When you override a method, calling `super` will run the original method that you overrode, since this doesn't happen automatically.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, it is a bad sign that you have a JPanel that implements Runnable.  In Java, all UI work (here you are using Swing components) is done from the Event Dispatching Thread - having an actual Swing component (your Intro class is a JPanel) Runnable flies in the face of that.

Answer (score 3):

Suggestions:

- Anytime you add a new component to a container, you have to tell the layout managers to layout the new and existing components. This is done by calling `revalidate()` on the JPanel receiving the button. You also should call `repaint()` on the JPanel after this.
- You shouldn't do any of this in a background thread.
- Most important read the Swing tutorials as they will tell you all of this and more.